# How to convert similar record as one record & reflect single time in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

In one table **tbl1** data is like-

```
ID     Desc. Amount  Org.     Date
1001   abc   125     Equity   12-Mar-18
1001   abc    50     Equity   12-Mar-18
1001   def   150     Market   12-Mar-18
1001   def   200     Market   12-Mar-18   
1001   def   100     Market   12-Mar-18
```

But due to data repetition I want for the same organization, amount would be **SUM**   and the data would be single times only & reflect into the table like wise-

```
ID     Desc. Amount  Org.     Date
1001   abc   175     Equity   12-Mar-18
1001   def   450     Market   12-Mar-18
```

I want that these above 5 data replace with below 2 data and store into the table. Means 5 data replace with these 2 data & only these 2 data reflect on the table.

Comment: For your sample data, you could use a simple `SUM` with `GROUP BY` statetment. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `aggregation`, which is what you haven't done yet

```
select ID, Desc, sum(Amount) Amount, Org, Date
from table t
group by ID, Desc, Org, Date
```

Comment: Thanks but this one i also know. I want that these above 5 data replace with below 2 data and store into the table. Means 5 data replace with these 2 data & only these 2 data reflect on the table.

Comment: @ShahinP.. For instance there are two options 1, Truncate table after the aggregation & insert the data  2. Re-create or add composite primary keys on `(ID, Desc, Org., Date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the records temporarily, truncating and then re-inserting  would be an option, especially if your data is huge.

Another approach as a two step process, without truncating or creating DDLs would be to update all the amount to the required value and then deleting the duplicates.

```
UPDATE tbl1 t1
SET Amount = (
        SELECT sum(Amount)
        FROM tbl1 t2
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
            AND t2.Descr = t1.Descr
            AND t2.Org = t1.Org
            AND t2.Date_t = t1.Date_t
        );

DELETE
FROM tbl1
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(rowid)
        FROM tbl1
        GROUP BY ID
            ,Descr
            ,Amount
            ,Org
            ,Date_t
        )  ;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/227063/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and analytic functions to do it in a single statement:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e97d/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, "Desc", Amount, Org, "Date" ) AS
  SELECT 1001, 'abc', 125, 'Equity', DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 'abc',  50, 'Equity', DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 'def', 150, 'Market', DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 'def', 200, 'Market', DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 'def', 100, 'Market', DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         SUM( Amount ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY ID, "Desc", Org, "Date"
           ) AS Amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY ID, "Desc", Org, "Date"
             ORDER BY ROWNUM
           ) AS rn
  FROM    table_name
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Amount = src.Amount
  DELETE WHERE rn > 1
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e97d/3/1)**:

```
|   ID | Desc | AMOUNT |    ORG |                 Date |
|------|------|--------|--------|----------------------|
| 1001 |  abc |    175 | Equity | 2018-03-12T00:00:00Z |
| 1001 |  def |    450 | Market | 2018-03-12T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Was thinking about this.. then changed my mind... +1